# Why is killing Myrtle considered as a murder committed by Riddle?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Technically, Tom's soul is split every time he kills someone himself. However, Myrtle was killed by the basilisk. So why is this considered as Tom killing her, and why did it cause his soul to split?

Comment: Hey @Vadzim, could reword your question a bit?  It is currently very difficult to understand what it is you are asking

Comment: @MagikarpMaster I reworded question.

Comment: "why did it cause his soul to split" - did it split at this event?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok It killed her on _his_ orders, therefore he's responsible.

Comment: @HorusKol It did, it was his first kill and he put the piece of his soul that split off into the diary, making it his first horcrux. It's why the memory of Tom Riddle preserved in the diary is such a young image.

Comment: This exact question is addressed in the dupe; **Q.** "*Quite likely the Basilisk would have killed Myrtle whether or not Riddle told it to. Still, this counted as murder. What, then, counts as a murder that splits one's soul?* **A.** "*Certainly if I murdered people in the real world by siccing rabid starving bears on them, the police would arrest me for murder and I would likely be convicted.*"